# Calling (xts) objects / datasets / variables with a list of their names (strings)

Tags: r, string, loops, variables

it is possibly a very simple question but I looked up the Internet for hours without any idea - that's why I ask here.

I have a csv-file with stock-symbols (e.g. DAI.F, PAH3.F, GRU.F, ...). With package quantmod I get historical stock data by Yahoo and for each stock-symbol an xts-Object is created in my workspace with the same name as the symbol.

My problem is that I don't know how to loop through these xts-objects by the content of the csv-file. The names are stored as strings in `symbols_watchlist`

Last row of the code is the problem: `stock <- symbols_watchlist[i]`

`stock` should be one of the xts-objects that are importet for each loop. With `stock <- symbols_watchlist[i]` it just becomes a string with the name of the symbol from `symbols_watchlist` - please see attached picture (Example of Workspace in RStudio).

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(readr)

start_date_5year <- Sys.Date()-1826
end_date <- Sys.Date()

watchlist <-  read.csv("D:/Watchlist.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
symbols_watchlist <- watchlist$Yahoo_label

getSymbols(watchlist$Yahoo_label,src='yahoo', from = start_date_5year, to = end_date) 

for (i in 1:length(symbols_watchlist)){
  stock <- symbols_watchlist[i]
}
```

Example of Workspace in RStudio

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mget` to get all the symbols in the list.

```
list_of_symbols <- mget(symbols_watchlist)
```

You can then use `lapply` to loop over them and apply any function on each one of them.

```
lapply(list_of_symbols, function(x) {
     #Do something with each symbol
})
```

---

Using `for` loop you can do this one by one with `get`.

```
for (i in symbols_watchlist) {
   stock <- get(i)
   #Do something with stock
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what you want as your end result and which framework to work with. You are using tidyquant but using `getSymbols` from quantmod to get the data. You can either get a list of xts objects or a data.frame with all the data.

Using quantmod (no tidyquant required), result a list of xts objects:

```
library(quantmod)

symbols_watchlist <- c("DAI.F", "GRU.F", "IQ8.F", "PAH3.F")
start_date_5year <- Sys.Date()-1826
end_date <- Sys.Date()

stocks <- lapply(symbols_watchlist, getSymbols, from = start_date_5year, to = end_date, auto.asssign = FALSE)
names(stocks) <- symbols_watchlist
```

Using tidyquant, result a data.frame:

```
library(tidyquant)

df_stocks <- tq_get(symbols_watchlist, from = start_date_5year, to = end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints!